# How do i invoke a complete groovy statement in java?

Tags: groovy

I hava a groovy util class and contains some simple methods, just like this:

```
class Util {
   def sum(int a, int b) {
       a + b;
   }
}
```

And in java i want to invoke the statement "Util.sum(1, 2);" dynamically, in this case, how can i do it?

Comment: https://docs.groovy-lang.org/docs/next/html/documentation/#_groovyscriptengine

Comment: What have you tried and how has it failed?  Please add the Java code, that does not work and your compiler or runtime errors or any log that helps to find the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if I understand your question too simplistically, but this works.

Util.groovy:

```
package callgroovy

class Util {
    def sum(int a, int b) {
        a + b;
    }
 }
```

And CallUtil.java:

```
package callgroovy;

import callgroovy.Util;

public class CallUtil {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //explicit declaration
        Util util = new Util();
        System.out.println(util.sum(1, 2));
        //or dynamic
        System.out.println(new Util().sum(3, 4));
    }

}
```